# Setting up Universal Repeater - ESSID and SSID - what is the difference?

Tags: wireless-access-point, repeater

I have a wireless network at home, using one wireless router.

IT's SSID is: home_112

I want to extend the coverage, and adding a D-link switch, that can act also as a

> universal repeater

However, during setup, I need to give both an SSID and an ESSID (main SSID) to the D-link.

My original thought was that I give my UR the SAME SSID as my router (thinking that I have a single network with the same name) but I can't seem to make it work.

So what is it? IF I gave a different SSID (and used the router ESSID as main point) I get BOTH networks detected

- Original - with low signal
- And new one - with Strong signal
- But I am NOT automatically transferred to the new one, as it is not recognized by my devices.
- And if I give the same name - I only see the one with low signal - and no signal at all if I go a little off-connection.

So what am I doing wrong? - OR: which is the right track?

Comment: What model is the D-Link repeater?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good guide over on [source daddy](http://sourcedaddy.com/networking/bssid-ssid-and-essid.html) which explains the difference between BSSID, SSID, and ESSID.

To act as a repeater, the SSID probably refers to the mac address of your original wifi adapter wheras the ESSID would be the name you want it to appear as (i.e. the same as the original network). The documentation that comes with the D-Link probably has more detailed information on what it expects though...

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.cwnp.com/forums/posts?postNum=294480) says that technically there's no such thing as an ESSID, but rather an SSID shared by all by all the BSS in the ESS.

Practically, they're the same.